# Wordpress rewrite rule not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to implement some rewrite rules on a wordpress website to rewrite my urls like:

glossary/?terms=a

to

glossary/terms/a

I have added the following code to my functions.php and have flushed the rewrites but havent had no luck?

```
add_rewrite_rule('^glossary/([0-9]+)/?', 'glossary/?terms=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction or advise what is incorrect with the above?

Comment: [0-9] matches 'conaints a number', like /?id=4. Are you using IDs or text (the sample 'a' implies a string, so strings must be matched).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this to work with the following rewrite rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^glossary/term/([a-z]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=glossary&terms=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top');
```